# Use a cookie value in a linq where statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq, cookies

I have a linq WHERE statment where I'm wanting to use a cookie value string (aspxauth) to match up to a string in a table, however I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

The code is:

```
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[".aspxauth"];
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        string cookieUser = authCookie.Value;

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[".aspxauth"] != null)
            {
                var loginStatus = new UsersDataContext();
                var loginstatus = from s in loginStatus.sessions
                                  where s.aspxauth == cookieUser
                                  select s;

                var x = loginstatus.FirstOrDefault().UserId.ToString();
```

If I remove the where statement I dont get the error.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong here??

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the `cookieUser` value null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that none of the elements in the `loginStatus.sessions` sequence match the condition of the where clause, causing `loginstatus.FirstOrDefault()` to return null, so when you try to access `.UserId`, you get the null reference exception.

You should check for null yourself and handle the case:

```
var firstLoginStatusMatch = loginstatus.FirstOrDefault();

if (firstLoginStatusMatch  == null)
{
   // Handle no match
}

var userId = firstLoginStatusMatch.UserId.ToString()
```

I would also suggest naming your variables to be more descriptive. You have two variables of the same name but with different casing, making the code very hard to scan.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that at least one of the sessions items is null, or that your where statement filtered the collection down to zero items.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if no elements match, that is where `where s.aspxauth == cookieUser` is false for every element in `loginStatus.sessions`. FirstOrDefault() will return the default value for an object, which is null.